# Permissions error reading Teams 1:1 chat with Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to retrieve the history for a 1:1 bot-user chat with a Teams bot installed in personal scope. The bot (service principal's) has application permissions `TeamsAppInstallation.ReadWriteSelfForUser.All`.

Demo user found the app and added it to her personal scope. The app shows up in the left panel and has "Uninstall" on its context menu, so I assume it is actually installed. (Also, `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<user-id>/teamwork/installedApps` says `AppEntitlement id: '<app-installation-id>' already exists in thread : '' for user : '<user-id>'`).

When using `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<user-id>/teamwork/installedApps/<base64-chat-id>/chat` I get info on the chat:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#chats/$entity",
  "id": "19:<user-id>_<teams-app-id>@unq.gbl.spaces",
  "topic": null,
  "createdDateTime": "2023-10-20T13:11:26.691Z",
  "lastUpdatedDateTime": "2023-10-20T13:11:27.011Z",
  "chatType": "oneOnOne",
  "webUrl": "https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/19%3A<user-id>_<teams-app-id>%40unq.gbl.spaces/0?tenantId=<tenant-id>",
  "tenantId": "<tenant-id>",
  "viewpoint": null,
  "onlineMeetingInfo": null
}
```

As expected, trying to retrieving the chat history with `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats/19:<user-id>_<teams-app-id>@unq.gbl.spaces/messages`  produces error `Missing role permissions on the request. API requires one of 'Chat.Read.WhereInstalled, Chat.ReadWrite.WhereInstalled, ChatMessage.Read.All, Chat.Read.All, Chat.ReadWrite.All, ChatMessage.Read.Chat'. Roles on the request 'TeamsAppInstallation.ReadWriteSelfForUser.All, Group.Selected'. Resource specific consent grants on the request ''.` However, if I add `Chat.Read.WhereInstalled` and try to read the history of this I get `Forbidden`:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Not allowed to access the resource because no apps with Azure AD App ID '<teams-app-id>' were found installed in the chat.",
    "innerError": {...}
  }
}
```

If I change the bot permissions to include `Chat.Read.All` I am allowed to retrieve the chat history, but that is unacceptably high permissions for this case. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please note that retrieving the list of messages in a chat requires these permissions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions. It requires the following application permissions - https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBuoa.png.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT That's possible. However, that means that the error messges is wrong when it says that `Chat.Read.WhereInstalled` is required. It also quite strange that an app can 1) find info on its chat with a user and 2) receive its messages via botservice webhook, but cannot read the history unless it has unreasonably high permissions.

Comment: Additionally, the `.WhereInstalled` permission has the following description in Azure Entra ID "Allows the app to read all one-to-one or group chat messages in Microsoft Teams for chats where the associated Teams application is installed, without a signed-in user."

Comment: we will check this and get back to you.

Comment: We have the following update from engineering team, 
 
We were able to repro the issue and are looking into fixing it. This however might take a while due to the complexity involved in the fix.